# phonegap barcode scanner with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, zxing

I created a new android project using [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) tutorial and it works fine.
I then tried to follow [this](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/installing-barcode-plugin-for-phonegap.html) tutorial so i could implement a barcode reading capabilities for my application but i encounter this error when running the application:

-`The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\myname\workspace\CaptureActivity\bin\captureactivity.jar'`

I just started using `ecilpse` and `phonegap` so this might be trivial for some of you but i tried to re-create this application several times and allways ended up with the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yoav, try using my example projects. You should just be able to import them into Eclipse and get the sample project working pretty quickly.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/10/barcode-scanner-example-projects.html

As for the problem you are having do you see any errors in the CaptureActivity project that would prevent the jar from being built?

Comment: Thanks a lot. is it possible to change the size of the scan window or implement the scan in the `index.html` page?

Comment: @Yoav you'd have to dig around in the CaptureActivity project to change the size of the scan window. I can't think of a way to embed the scanner in the index.html.